# Effect of two independent variables on a dependent variable, each containing several factors in Likert scale form

Tags: regression, predictor, likert, dependent-variable

For example, the first independent variable consists of 30 factors, the second independent variable consists of 21 factors, and the dependent variable consists of 21 factors. There are four options for each factor.

What is the analysis method to use if I need to know the effect of the two independent variables on the dependent variable?

Comment: I think your use of the word factor here is a bit confusing. Lets take the first IV with 30 factors. Do you mean this is a Likert scale test with 30 items (which are summed/averaged together), each of which containing 4 levels of rating the scale?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand yes it is, sorry for my word using

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you have the following:

- Two IVs which are composites containing 30 and 21 items respectively.
- One DV which is a composite containing 21 items.
- All of these three composites contain 4-level Likert scale items.

*You have a couple of options here.*

The easiest option is to simply sum up the composites for each person, then run a multiple linear regression with your three variables. Because it's not assumed that your composites are reliable, I also advise getting reliability coefficients for each composite. Typically people use Cronbach's alpha, but I am more in preference of McDonald's omega if you have an understanding of factor analysis. And of course, you want to ensure that you have a decent understanding of some of the core assumptions of linear regression so you know you have met them in some way. I recommend reading *Regression and Other Stories* referenced below to get a better understanding of regression in general if you don't already have a base understanding of how regression works.

The drawback to just using a linear regression is that it will not capture the attenuation bias that results from the uncertainty in reliability from your items (Kline, 2023). To include this uncertainty into the model, another option is to run the same multiple linear regression, but you model the items in your data into a structural equation model (SEM) that includes the items. However, some drawbacks to SEM are that it requires very large samples and often necessitates even more stringent rules about fitting the data.

My personal suggestion is that if you have a small sample, I would go ahead with the regression with the suggestions I made. There is no need to overcomplicate things if you don't have the resources to do so.

##### References

- Flora, D. B. (2020). Your coefficient alpha is probably wrong, but which coefficient omega is right? A tutorial on using R to obtain better reliability estimates. Advances in Methods and Practices in Psychological Science, 3(4), 484–501. https://doi.org/10.1177/2515245920951747
- Gelman, A., Hill, J., & Vehtari, A. (2022). Regression and other stories. Cambridge University Press.
- Kline, R. B. (2023). Principles and practice of structural equation modeling (5th ed.). The Guilford Press.

Comment: sorry, I can't access the book of Regression, but why it is permittable to add up the items for each individual? could you explain the concept of it?

Comment: Let's say I test a child on their ability to read, and the only way I do that is giving them a single true/false question on a gap fill activity. Do you think that is an adequate way to measure their overall reading ability? Your gut feeling should be "no", as they could have got the answer correct by chance, the item we gave was too easy, or they had just read a sentence that day that contained that word. If we instead provide the child with a litany of reading questions, we can ensure we are covering a wide range of ability and not capitalizing on chance outcomes.

Comment: The same goes for any test of ability, emotion, etc. The reading example is fortunately more concrete and easier to assess. A lot of psychology is not so easy to narrow down in that way, which increases the need for a wide range of items that hopefully capture the essence of the construct being measured. This is also why we should assess reliability, as we can't know our composite is doing a good job by intuition alone. Btw if you want to read the regression book, the authors provide a free link [here.](https://users.aalto.fi/~ave/ROS.pdf)

Comment: wawar, in addition to what Shawn said: It sounds like you have human participants who have responded to your questions using Likert scales. Are the questions from an established measure or have you created the questions yourself? If the former, find the original source for the measure. In that source the authors of the measure describe how they created the items and their justification for combining them into composite scales. In general, averaging items that belong to the same measure (based on theory and scale development work) is very very common in psychology and social sciences.